# Implement ACL using Policies in Multi Auth Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, acl

AuthService Provider:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

        $gate->define('show-user', function ($admin) {
            return $admin->hasRole('Admin');
        });
    }
```

Admin is a Auth Guard

Controller :

```
public function edit($admin) {
  if (Gate::allows('show-user'))
            return 'allow';
        else {
            return 'deny';
        }
   }
```

Gate Always returns 'Deny'

I have a repository function doing the same job.

```
public function checkPermission($admin) {
   return $this->auth->hasRole('Admin') || $this->auth->id ===    $admin->id;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you comparing `$admin->roles` to a string? From the property name looks like it might return more than one role, maybe as a comma-separated string or array? You have to make sure you check that 'Admin' is one of the roles.

For example if it returns an array you can do:

`return in_array('Admin', $admin->roles);`

Comment: Admin is a role. I was testing ACL. So did not go for complicated logic.